# Why is my navbar not the same as the original code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar [here](https://themertzy.github.io/ResultHeap/index.html). But I need it to look like this navbar [here](https://codepen.io/sivanpandian/pen/MpVBBE). I'm not sure what the issue is but I assume it has to do with my styling.

This is what I want the navbar to look like

```html
     <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Open your console (F12 for Chrome), you'll see the problem https://imgur.com/a/uoUG2GN

Comment: @blex This still doesn't work. I removed the imports that arent needed and I have the script code inside the html.

Comment: You need to provide your css

Comment: https://github.com/themertzy/themertzy.github.io/blob/master/ResultHeap/css/main.css

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the code for both demo. I noticed there seems to be multiple script reference of jquery and also multiple stylesheet reference of bootstrap. I also noticed in between the code you also have multiple calls to `AOS.init();` file. First of all, you need to restructure your code and remove these multiple references.

The main reason why you are having different results is that you are using a different bootstrap version compared to the codepen sample.

A simple and quick fix would be to comment out line 20 which is a duplicate reference of bootstrap CSS and update line 10 to use bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment out - line 20

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Update - line 10 to use this

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

instead of

```
https://themertzy.github.io/ResultHeap/css/vendor/bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Version is incompatible and imports are not in order.
I have given you a pull request in github.
That is working for Nav bar. But may have error in other components.
Please check it and merge it.
https://github.com/themertzy/themertzy.github.io/pull/2

Comment: @Mertz can you check on this changes